# perform multiple separate transforms, in different css blocks

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

i have something like this

```
<div id="btns">
    <div id="btn1"></div>
    <div id="btn2"></div>
    <div id="btn3"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#btns >div{

  //makes each of my btns pop out at different timings
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#btn1{

  transition-delay:  .6s;
}
.btnsOut #btn1{
   //makes btn pop out
   //this works
  transform: translate(-50px, 40px);

}
#btns.btnsOut >div:hover {
     //hover effect for poped out btn
     // this doesnt work, other css rules in this block works, but not transform
      transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

ok so i simplified my code a lot.  my question is basically.  when a class is added to my btn divs they pop out, this works great.   but now my problem is, that when i already transformed the div in having it pop out, it doesn't want to transform it on the hover too.   so my question is, can you perform two separate transforms, in two different css blocks?  is this at all possible?

Comment: It is quite possible: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dLssqpe/) (with some modifications). 

You forgot the `#` before `btn1` in your css. A suggestion: if you move/rotate using `:hover` then you'll get flickering; better to use a JS handler and `addClass` in that case.

Comment: your right, it actually does work.   do you per chance know why its moving diagonally instead of rotating in hover?

Comment: The div is full-width, so the center is quite a bit to the right. See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dLssqpe/2/). One solution is to have 2 layers of effects ([another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dLssqpe/3/) )

Comment: thanks man.  id accept your answer, but dont think there is a option to accept a comment

Answer (score 0):

Stacked animations are quite possible - it didn't work because of using `btn1` instead of `#btn1` in the CSS.

To have the second rotation effect not be affected by the first translation effect it is easiest to add a nested div: the outer one for the translation, and the inner one for the rotation.

To have the center of rotation be (more or less) the center of the text, the inner div's width must be reduced, using `display: inline-block`.

The essential modifications are:

HTML:

```
<div id="btn1p">
    <div id="btn1">B1</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btnsOut #btn1p {
    transform: translate(50px, 0);
}
#btns > div > div:hover {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dLssqpe/3/) and here is the code example:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("ani");
        $('#btns').addClass('btnsOut');
    }, 1000)
})
```

```css
#btns div {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#btns > div > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
#btn1 {
    transition-delay: .6s;
}
.btnsOut #btn1p {
    transform: translate(50px, 0);
}
#btns > div > div:hover {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btns">
    <div id="btn1p">
        <div id="btn1">B1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="btn2">B2</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="btn3">B3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```